# Unable to add Tableview cell value to JSON Parameter, coming nil why? in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, null, cell

I am adding tableview cell label text to `phNumArray`, in tableview i am getting all values but when i try to pass in service call then its coming nill why?

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var joinersTableView: UITableView!

var tablcellArray  = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: Namescell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Namescell") as! Namescell
    cell.empRoleLbl.text = empTeftfield.text

    tablcellArray.append((cell.empRoleLbl.text!))

    print("employee names array \(tablcellArray)")// here coming all appende values

    return cell
}

func getPostData(params: [String:Any]) -> Data? {
        return try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.joinersTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func callPostApi() {
        print("tableview emp values\(tablcellArray)")// here array values not coming

        let url            = URL(string: "http://itaag-env-1/")!
        var request        = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        print("appende values \(tablcellArray)")
        try? request.setMultipartFormData(["contactsList": "\(tablcellArray)"], encoding: .utf8)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                           self.joinersTableView.reloadData()
                           }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, _ in
            if let data = data, let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {

            }
        }.resume()
    }
  }
```

in tableview cellfor row appended values coming.. but when i try to bring that array in `callPostApi` func then `tablcellArray` showing nil why?

please share your knowledge, please try to solve this error.

Comment: Never change your datamodel from inside `cellForRowAt`

Answer (score 0):

firstly change

```
var tablcellArray  = [String]()
```

to

```
var tablcellArray  = [String]
```

then in your cellForRowAt try to access your data such as

```
let empTeftfield =  tablcellArray[indexPath.row]
```

if this line prints correctly

```
cell.empRoleLbl.text = empTeftfield.text
```

this should work.

if not prints your value reload tableview after fetching data from api. you shouldnt add values to your array in your conditions.